# Shift-Select in Matlab Editor lagging

Tags: java, ssd, freeze, matlab, editor

I have very peculiar problem in Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 using Matlab (both R2014a and R2014b) I am not able to solve for almost a year (maybe even more). This problem persists on my second machine I just built, therefore I don't think it is hardware specific, unless... (we'll get into that later).

When I was using my ASUS U43SD Notebook, after first install, everything was fine, but after a while editing a Matlab using Shift-Select (with keyboard arrows) became hell. Lagging, freezing, clugging. I tried everything, reinstalling software, purging and reinstalling Java, everything, with no results.

After a week ago, I built a completely new machine, desktop for this time, since I needed performance for my work. I installed Matlab and everything was perfect, however - it is now fifth day from built when Matlab does the same as before on my notebook. The most interesting thing is that at first it runs fine, but after Matlab starts to be a bad boy, it keeps its attitude. Formatting, OS reinstalling, none of these will resolve the problem.

The only thing right now that might have some impact I can think of is my SSD disk. I was using Corsair Force GS in my notebook and it is the only think that made it into my new desktop, everything else except that is new. Can it be the drive? Could it be some kind of weekly trim thing that starts after a week, therefore messing with something and persisting even after OS reinstall and complete drive format? I am clueless...

Help me please, I beg you.

**EDIT:**
Some suggested informations:

free --human

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7,5G       4,7G       2,8G       898M        77M       2,2G
-/+ buffers/cache:       2,5G       5,0G
Swap:         3,9G         0B       3,9G
```

iostat

```
Linux 3.16.0-30-generic (bluecore-pc)   3.2.2015    _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
       2,39    0,00    0,42    0,03    0,00   97,15

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              12,32       135,15       279,33     763925    1578952
sdb               0,05         1,28         0,00       7224          0
sdc               0,11         5,05         0,00      28528          0
```

top

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                            
 5196 bluecore  20   0 5632056 591308 167216 S   1,7  7,5   0:20.93 MATLAB                                             
 1324 root      20   0  857652 113240  99576 S   0,7  1,4   1:29.43 Xorg                                               
 2200 bluecore  20   0   45080   3752   2128 S   0,7  0,0   0:19.10 dbus-daemon                                        
 2300 bluecore  20   0 1743472 229976  66284 S   0,7  2,9   0:59.34 compiz                                             
 2494 bluecore  20   0  748324  28128  22896 S   0,7  0,4   0:22.08 psensor                                            
 2543 bluecore  20   0   56568   6464   4824 S   0,7  0,1   0:13.85 gconfd-2                                           
 3780 bluecore  20   0 1285176 448020  58000 S   0,7  5,7   5:37.95 chrome                                             
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:01.84 rcu_sched                                          
 2305 bluecore  20   0  652396  34896  24688 S   0,3  0,4   0:08.54 unity-panel-ser                                    
 2822 bluecore  20   0 1037712 321592  60232 S   0,3  4,1   0:39.09 chrome                                             
 3708 bluecore  20   0 1295048 491160  57400 S   0,3  6,3   1:54.25 chrome                                             
 3892 bluecore  20   0  656388  35420  26996 S   0,3  0,5   0:03.68 gnome-terminal                                     
 5378 root      20   0   29484   3504   2736 R   0,3  0,0   0:00.02 top                                                
    1 root      20   0   29712   4400   2572 S   0,0  0,1   0:00.82 init                                               
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                           
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/0                                        
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                       
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.64 kworker/u16:0                                      
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.29 rcuos/0                                            
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.26 rcuos/1                                            
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.23 rcuos/2                                            
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.24 rcuos/3                                            
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.11 rcuos/4                                            
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.10 rcuos/5                                            
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.11 rcuos/6                                            
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.12 rcuos/7                                            
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                             
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/0                                            
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/1                                            
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/2                                            
   20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/3                                            
   21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/4                                            
   22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/5                                            
   23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/6                                            
   24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/7                                            
   25 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/0                                        
   26 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/0                                         
   27 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/1                                         
   28 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/1                                        
   29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                        
   30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0                                        
   31 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                                       
   32 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/2                                         
   33 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.06 migration/2                                        
   34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                                        
   35 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0                                        
   36 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H                                       
   37 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/3                                         
   38 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/3                                        
   39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3                                        
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 kworker/3:0                                        
   41 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H                                       
   42 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/4                                         
   43 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.45 migration/4                                        
   44 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/4                                        
   46 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H                                       
   47 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/5                                         
   48 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/5                                        
   49 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/5                                        
   50 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/5:0                                        
   51 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/5:0H                                       
   52 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/6                                         
   53 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/6                                        
   54 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/6                                        
   55 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/6:0                                        
   56 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/6:0H                                       
   57 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/7                                         
   58 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/7                                        
   59 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/7                                        
   60 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/7:0                                        
   61 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/7:0H                                       
   62 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khelper                                            
   63 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                          
   64 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 netns                                              
   65 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                         
   66 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 writeback                                          
   67 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksmd                                               
   68 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.41 khugepaged                                         
   69 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 crypto                                             
   70 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                        
   71 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 bioset                                             
   72 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kblockd                                            
   73 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                            
   74 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khubd                                              
   75 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 md                                                 
   76 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                         
   78 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.10 kworker/2:1                                        
   80 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kswapd0                                            
   81 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark                                      
   82 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea                                    
   94 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                           
   95 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm                                    
   96 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.05 kworker/6:1                                        
   97 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.16 kworker/0:1                                        
   98 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf                                      
   99 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:2                                        
  118 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 deferwq                                            
  119 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 charger_manager
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what's the output to: `sudo free --human` `sudo iostat` `sudo top` when you're having this problem?  Please test this on the 14.04 machine and [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: I edited the post and added those informations. Corsair Force GS is drive sdb. It is not even the drive OS is installed at, that is on Samsung 850 EVO - sda. I don't know if drive has to do anything with it, but it is the only thing both PCs have in common and it is suspicious... Also I am currently running on 14.10, but both 14.04 and 14.10 have the exact same behavior.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I am dual booting Windows, which is located at Corsair Force GS - that is drive sdb.

Comment: This info is when you *have* the problem???

Comment: Yes. The problem is constant, immediately when I run Matlab. It does not present itself in any way, does not start after a while, it is just weird from the start. Every day.

Comment: I'm sorry... I can't help you any further then... I had a hunch it was your swap or IO, but that doesn't seem to be the problem...  My apologies to have inconvenienced you!  :(

Comment: Thank you for your time anyway. :-) This thing really is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all this time, I think I have - absolutely by accident - found the answer.

It looks like the reason for this laggines is **glipper**. Addon for clipboard in Ubuntu. I have no idea this is the real problem, but all I can say now is that if I terminate glipper, Matlab behaves correctly.

Hope it helps someone in the future, as this is obviously a VERY specific problem.